# Run a windows program in wine on a remote server using gnu parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu, bioinformatics, wine, gnu-parallel

I have a working script kindly provided by Mark Setchell (and also Ole Tange) from this forum which allows me to use "parallel" to run a multiple instances of the windows program "msvar.exe" under wine. I currently run up to 20 instances on a dual hexacore computer. Here is the script (this one is for use on Centos 6.8 which doesn't have the realpath command);

```
doit() {
   echo Processing $1
#   cd $(dirname $(realpath "$1"));
cd $(dirname $(readlink -f "$1"));
   WINEPREFIX=$HOME/slot{%} wine /home/msvar/msvar0.4.1b/msvar.exe
}
export -f doit

find /home/msvar/MSVAR_ORC_NEWUPLOAD -name INTFILE -type f | parallel doit
```

I have several other dual hexacore servers and would like to use "parallel" to run more instances of "msvar.exe" on these other servers. I have read the "parallel" documents but am confused about how to incorporate remote servers into this script. Following one example in the help file I tried adding the server by adding "-S server IP address" between "parallel" and the "doit" command in the script but this just caused an error to say "doit" is not a command, as you would expect. How would I modify this script to incorporate remote servers into the cpu pool used by "parallel" so that I can run more instances of "msvar.exe" ?

Comment: I think we are going to need to put `doit()` into a little `bash` script that the other hexacores can read/execute from your login directory or similar. Are the data files visible in the same place on the additional servers - i.e. via a SHARE? Or would **GNU Parallel** have to distribute the data files too?

Comment: I'd like to use parallel to distribute, return and clean-up (maybe the -trc option), that's one of the attractions of parallel for me. We use this program a lot and my eventual aim is to have a simple web interface so doing the data handling via parallel makes sense. I'm trying the --env variable (something about the environment ?) in parallel as it seems to have potential, but just as before, I'm quickly hitting my level of incompetence and I fear my brain will explode. This is my first ever forum discussion so I don't know if it's allowed, but I'd happily do this as a little contract.

Comment: I added in the **GNU Parallel** tag so that Ole sees this. Unless he doesn't find time to answer in the next couple of days, I will defer to him on this as I don't want to confuse things by adding my own misconceptions. I think Ole is probably your man here - he normally answers all questions excellently and promptly.

Comment: What files does `msvar` read? What files does it produce? Which files should be copied to the remote machine, and which files should be copied back?

Comment: Again: To give a proper answer we really need more understanding of `msvar`. What does the dir look like before `msvar` is run? and after? Which files can be ignored? What does .. (parent dir) look like?

Comment: A data folder has 3 files infile, init_v_file, INTFILE. If msvar.exe is run in this folder it will create a number of results files in the same folder called out1, out2, out3 etc depending on the init_v_file setup, but not usually not more than out30. If I have 20 different models I will have 20 folders each with an identical infile and INTFILE but a slightly different init_v_file. I have all of these data folders under a single parent folder - eg: parent folder "msvar_linear_ORB" has 15 subfolders "line1", "line2" etc each with an infile, init_v_file and INTFILE. I need all of these files.

Comment: Update your question with this - preferably with a real example.

Answer (score 1):

I am puzzled that your script works due to this line:

```
   WINEPREFIX=$HOME/slot{%} wine /home/msvar/msvar0.4.1b/msvar.exe
```

GNU Parallel does not replace {%} in functions but only in the command on the command line, so I think your WINEPREFIX is set to something you do not expect.

This should give 1 2 3 4 with a recent version of GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -S 4/: echo {%} ::: a b c d
```

To run jobs remotely you need ssh to work. So this must work:

```
parallel -S server1 echo ::: foo bar
```

You also need to export the function to the server. So you need a recent version of GNU Parallel where this works:

```
myfunc() { echo OK "$@"; }
export -f myfunc
parallel -S server1 --env myfunc myfunc ::: this works
```

You also need to transfer files, so `rsync` must be installed on both ends, so this works:

```
myfunc() { echo OK "$@"; echo in myfunc >> "$1".result; }
export -f myfunc
echo foofile > foo.txt
echo barfile > bar.txt
parallel --trc {.}.result -S server1 --env myfunc myfunc {.} ::: foo.txt bar.txt
cat foo.result bar.result
```

Your `find` command gives absolute path to the file, but we need it transferred to a position relative to the workdir on the remote. The way to do that is to insert /./ in the path:

```
/foo/bar/quux/./baz
```

will read `/foo/bar/quux/baz` but copy it to `workdir/baz`. This will insert the /./ the correct place:

```
--transferfile '{= s:(.*)/:$1/./: =}'
```

It is not clear if you have a result file. If not, you can use `--transfer --cleanup` instead of `--trc {/.}.result`. It is also not clear if you only need the INTFILE as input, or if `msvar.exe` uses other files from the dir. The below assumes you only need that. Otherwise you need to add `--basefile otherfile` or `--transferfile {= s:(.*)/:$1/./: =}.other`.

Combining all of that (untested):

```
doit() {
   file="$1"
   dir="$2"
   slot="slot$3"
   cd "$dir" # Only used on local installation, remote uses --wd ...
   echo Processing "$file"
   WINEPREFIX=$HOME/"$slot" wine /home/msvar/msvar0.4.1b/msvar.exe
   # Assume msvar writes "$file".result
}
export -f doit
```

For local only:

```
find /home/msvar/MSVAR_ORC_NEWUPLOAD -name INTFILE -type f | parallel doit {} {//} {%}
```

When the above works, this should work for remote:

```
find /home/msvar/MSVAR_ORC_NEWUPLOAD -name INTFILE -type f | 
  parallel --wd ... --tf '{= s:(.*)/:$1/./: =}' --trc '{/.}'.result --env doit -S :,server1,server2.example.com doit {} {//} {%}
```

- --wd ... = create a temporary workdir on the remote machine
- --tf '{= s:(.*)/:$1/./: =}' = transfer {} to the workdir - save it as the name without dir
- --trc {/.}.result = after the transfer to the workdir, then run the command, then transfer {/.}.result back, then remove {} and {/.}.result from workdir
- --env doit = transfer the function `doit` so it can be used on the remote system
- -S :,server1,server2.example.com = use local machine and 2 servers
- doit = execute doit
- {} = argument
- {//} = dir of argument
- {%} = job slot

I will encourage you to read https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html as you are going into fairly advanced use of GNU Parallel.

Comment: Wow - excuse the delay I'm still using my meagre skills to try and get things working. I'm progressing but slowly. Msvar.exe is run using wine in a directory containing 3 files (data, config, model), it will process the data and write a ~20 results files in the same directory as the data. I may have >20 directories each with a different dataset, model or config. In my original find script I'd cd into each directory and run msvar.exe, using the "&" parameter I could run ~20 copies at once. Can parallel copy a folder of the folders over to the server, process and return the folders and results.